# Bajar cambios de un repositorio en github desde git

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, git-pull

Mi pregunta es como bajar los cambios de un repositorio remoto github desde git. Explico el contexto.
Existe un sistema que ya esta en producción del cual inicie el repo:

```
git init
git add
git commit -m
```

De hecho ya esta configurado.

Antes de ello descargue a modo local todo el proyecto lo inicialice. Luego cree un repositorio en github y subi el proyecto al repo remoto.

Tengo un servidor de desarrollo y clone el proyecto. Hago mis cambios en local, y los subo al serv. de desarrollo.

```
git push origin main
```

Hasta allí todo bien, los cambios se reflejan correctamente.
El punto es, ¿Cómo hacer o bajar los cambios a mi servidor de producción si allí esta el proyecto base?

La estructura del proyecto es la siguente:
5 carpetas o directorios y 20 archivos o file donde se realiza la programación.

Si ejecuto el git pull, se baja pero las carpetas al ser distintas porque internamente tienen otro contenido (en desarrollo solo pruebas y producción, archivos que se suben al sisetma) no se tiene porque modificar con los cambios.

Intente con lo siguente:

```
git fetch
git merge
```

Pero sin exito.
¿Existe algún comando o método para que solo bajar los cambios de los archivos o file donde se realiza la progamación?

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer un 'git clone' en el servidor de producción cada vez que necesites pasar el proyecto.

Comment: Podrías aclarar lo que comentas sobre "las carpetas al ser distintas..." y "no se tiene por qué modificar con los cambios"? Las carpetas no debieran ser distintas. Si ambbos ambientes apuntan a main la diferencia debiera ser sólo la generada por tus commits locales que no se hayan traído desde producción

Comment: ok. Lo que pasa en producción, las carpetas que indico estan guardados archivos y documentos que se trabajo con el sistema. En desarrollo, en las carpetas, solo hay un archivo index.html que solo esta para relleno. Entonces, yo al haber hecho el git push origin desde mi local al repositorio en blanco, se sube todo el proyecto con la estructura completa. En cambio en producción, si bajo los cambios, serian con las carpetas vacias. Eso es mi piedra en el zapato, bajar los cambios pero sin las carpetas, ya que si lo hago completo, me reemplazara todito y tendría problemas con los archivos.